# How to find the rank of the given matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, matrix-rank

How do you find the rank of this matrix

$\begin{bmatrix}
0 &1& 2&1\\
1&0&1&2\\
2&1&0&1\\
1&2&1&0
\end{bmatrix}$

**My try**:

I wrote $\begin{bmatrix}
0 &1& 2&1\\
1&0&1&2\\
2&1&0&1\\
1&2&1&0
\end{bmatrix}$ as $$\begin{bmatrix}
0 &1& 2&1\\
1&0&1&2\\
2&1&0&1\\
1&2&1&0
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 &1& 1&1\\
1&0&1&1\\
1&1&0&1\\
1&1&1&0
\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}
0 &0& 1&0\\
0&0&0&1\\
1&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&0
\end{bmatrix}$$

Now $\begin{bmatrix}
0 &1& 1&1\\
1&0&1&1\\
1&1&0&1\\
1&1&1&0
\end{bmatrix}$ has rank $3$ and $\begin{bmatrix}
0 &0& 1&0\\
0&0&0&1\\
1&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&0
\end{bmatrix}$ has rank $4$.

So using the fact that $rank(A+B)\le rank(A)+rank(B)$, I get $\begin{bmatrix}
0 &1& 2&1\\
1&0&1&2\\
2&1&0&1\\
1&2&1&0
\end{bmatrix}$ has rank less than equal to $7$ which is useless as a $4\times 4$ matrix has rank atmost $4$.

What can I do to calculate the rank of the matrix given above? Please help

Comment: How do you calculated the ranks of the two matrices?

Comment: Row reducing the matrix is probably the most basic way to solve this problem. But for fun, the matrix is circulant, so the orthogonal eigenvectors are $(1,1,1,1)^T$, $(1,-1,1,-1)^T$, $(1,i,-1,-i)^T$ and $(1,-i,-1,i)^T$. The corresponding eigenvalues are $4, 0, -2, -2$, so the rank is $3$.

Comment: @JimmyK4542; can you please explain whats a circulant matrix and how to obtain its eigenvalues]

Comment: @JimmyK4542; if you could please give a detailed answer, I will be grateful

Comment: @Math_Freak See the Wiki page on circulant matrices [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix).

Comment: Sylvester's Law of Inertia  $$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 &  - 2 & 1 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 1 &  - 1 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
0 & 1 & 2 & 1 \\ 
1 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\ 
2 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
1 & 2 & 1 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  - 1 &  - 1 \\ 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  - 2 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) $$ is diagonal $(2, - \frac{1}{2}, -4, 0 )$

Answer (score 1):

Observe that $R_3=R_2+R_4-R_1$. So rank$\leq 3$. Now check to see if $R_1,R_2, R_4$ are linearly independent. The check is fairly straightforward because the columns of the $3 \times 4$ matrix (after deleting $R_3$)
\begin{bmatrix}
0 &1& 2&1\\
1&0&1&2\\
1&2&1&0
\end{bmatrix}
can be easily seen to be forming a basis for $\Bbb{R}^3$. This means the rank of this matrix is $3$, hence the rank of the original matrix is also $3$.

Comment: Four columns cannot be a basis for $\mathbb R^3$. Probably you meant that they span $\mathbb R^3$.

Comment: @Bungo You are right, my mistake. What I wanted to say was that **some** columns (e.g. $C_1,C_2$ and $C_4)$ are forming a basis.

Answer (score 0):

You can also see that
$$\det\begin{bmatrix}
0 &1& 2&1\\
1&0&1&2\\
2&1&0&1\\
1&2&1&0
\end{bmatrix} = 0$$

but $$\det\begin{bmatrix}
0 &1& 2\\
1&0&1\\
2&1&0
\end{bmatrix} \neq 0$$